# Property of symplectic spaces

Tags: solution-verification, symplectic-linear-algebra

I have the following problem (which was posed an exercise): Let E be a real vector space with a symplectic form $\omega$ (that is a non-degenerate skew-symmetric bilineal form).

Suppose you have another skew symmetric form $\tau$ so that for some $C>0$:

$$
|
\tau(x,y)
|
\leq
C|
\omega(x,y)
|
,
\forall x,y\in E
$$

Then there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $\tau = c\omega$. I solved the problem like this:

Pick a symplectic basis of E: $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$, that is a basis so that $
0=\omega(x_i,x_j)=\omega(y_i,y_j)
$,
$
\omega(x_i,y_j)=
\delta_{i,j}
$. This basis always exists when there is a symplectic form.

Then the equation above implies that $\tau$ only depends on $\tau(x_i,y_i)=c_i$.
(Since al the other values of $\tau$ on basic elements are $0$).
If $c_i\neq c_j$ for some pair indexes, then:
$$
0<|c_1-c_2|
=
|\tau(x_i,y_i)-\tau(x_j,y_j)|
=
|\tau(x_i,y_i-y_j)-\tau(x_j,y_j-y_i)
|
=
|\tau(x_1+x_2,y_1-y_2)|
\leq
|\omega(x_1+x_2,y_1-y_2)|
=
|\omega(x_i,y_i)-\omega(x_j,y_j)|=0
$$

Which obviously is a contradiction. Is my proof right?

The reason I am suspicious is because the excercise in question ask you first about the case $\tau$
is skew-symmetric and then when it is not. Which gives me the impression that it either the result should be false when $\tau$ is not skew-symmetric or this case should be harder. But in my solution, which seems quite easy it not necessary to assume $\tau$ has any symetry.

Comment: You have used antisymmetry of $\tau$ to only consider $\tau(x_i,y_j)$.  If $\tau$ is not antisymmetric, you have only showed $c'=\tau(y_i,x_i)$ and $c=\tau(x_i,y_i)$ but not $c'+c=0$.

Comment: oh right, so I guess now I know how to find a counterexample for when $\tau$ is not skew-symmetric!

Comment: *Hint*: The inequality $\lvert\tau(x,y)\rvert\leq C\lvert\omega(x,y)\rvert$ evaluated on $x=y$ gives $\tau$ antisymmetric.